# Why are my iBeacons not being detected?

Tags: cllocationmanager, ibeacon, ios7.1, estimote

I set up my CLLocationManager as follows

```
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.region];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"CLBeaconRegion monitoring not available");
    }
    if ([CLLocationManager isRangingAvailable]) {
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.region];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"CLBeaconRegion ranging not available");
    }
```

locationManager:didEnterRegion: and locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: are never called. I am using iOS 7.1 and have the issue on both an iPad and and iPhone. I am using Estimote beacons.

Comment: are you sure your region is set up correctly with the UUID that matches the beacons?

Comment: Yes, everything worked as soon as I rebooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting the iOS device completely resolved the issue. Not sure if this is a bug in iOS or with the Estimote beacons. But it seems restarting is required. That immediately resolved the issues and I have had no issues since.

Comment: Hi there, this is a bug in iOS 7.1 Bluetooth stack. It's already been reported to Apple.

Comment: @WojtekBorowicz Is there a open radar filed for this? Do you know the number?

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/16644458 refers to this issue but is marked as duplicate and I cannot find the original one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, who would have thought that the default Windows solution would work on this as well :)